# How can I install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 64-bit?

Tags: software-installation

How do I install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal either by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut or by clicking on the terminal icon.

Download the latest Google Chrome .deb package with wget:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Installing packages on Ubuntu requires sudo privileges. Make sure you are running the following command as a user with sudo privileges.

Install the Google Chrome .deb package by typing:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Enter your password and wait for the successful installation. 
Then you can launch it by searching in activities pane.